# How to ECHO "complex" paths using batch files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the term "complex" very lightly since the paths themselves are not difficult to parse but I'm facing an issue anyway.

If I try to echo the following statements, It fails & I can't figure out why.

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
echo name:sc%%G >> create.txt
echo Q:\sc%%G >> create.txt
echo DHIWAKAR-PC:sc%%G:F >> paths.txt
)
```

If I replace the above piece of code with the one below, things are fine. Unfortunately, it also prints the quotes (""). Is there anyway to avoid this ?

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
echo "name:sc%%G" >> create.txt
echo "Q:\sc%%G" >> create.txt
echo "DHIWAKAR-PC:sc%%G:F" >> paths.txt
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
 (echo(name:sc%%G)>> create.txt
 (echo(Q:\sc%%G)>> create.txt
 (echo(DHIWAKAR-PC:sc%%G:F)>> paths.txt
)
```

the first may be fails because the digits are taken for streams numbers.

Comment: You can fix the stream number problem by moving the redirection to the beginning of the command.  `>>create.txt echo(name:sc%%G)`

Comment: @RyanBemrose `>>create.txt (echo(name:sc%%G)` as the `(` in `echo(` **is not** an opening parenthesis

Comment: Thanks @npocmaka. I'll try this and update you, but can you provide some information/link on what these "streams" & numbers are ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar - here's some info - http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html